# Porque Javascript retorna Infinity em vez de erro ao dividir por 0?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Quando eu faço a divisão de qualquer valor por zero, o Javascript, me retorna *`Infinity`*.

Minha dúvida é porque *Infinity*? *Infinity* é definido no Javascript, mas eu não consegui encontrar um uso para ela em nenhum caso.

Alguém sabe me dizer também, qual seria o uso dela?

Comment: Mas divisão por 0 da erro em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Eu sei, por isso a pergunta... porque no javascript me retorna Infinity? Infinity não é um erro.. Entendeu?

Comment: Outra coisa, o typeof do Infinity retorna "number"... porém Infinity - Infinity = Infinity;

Comment: No JS, `Infinity - Infinity` resulta em `NaN`, não em `Infinity`.

Comment: Perdão, é isso mesmo! Me confundi.

Comment: Deixo a resposta aqui para alguém traduzir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838301/in-javascript-why-does-zero-divided-by-zero-return-nan-but-any-other-divided-b

Comment: Não é qualquer divisão por zero que retorna Infinity. Zero dividido por zero retorna NaN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando divides algo por zero tens de ter alguma maneira de representar em JavaScript. Esta é a razão principal para a sua existência: a representação de uma entidade matemática.

Outro caso, imagina que precisas de saber o menor numero de uma dada array que tenhas, é util ter uma variável que seja "inbatível" para poder ir mudando o valor menor:

```js
var arr = [345435, 1, 744, 78899, 3e500];
let menor = Infinity;
for (let nr of arr) {
  if (nr < menor) menor = nr;
}

console.log(menor);
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio, agora vi um bom exemplo de uso para ela. Assim que liberar marco como correta a resposta

Comment: bom uso, costumo atribuir o primeiro valor da coleção quando preciso encontrar o maior ou menos de um conjunto e depois continuar comparando, mas gostei do Infinity =]

Answer (score 5):

Gostaria de acrescentar uma informação que não consta das respostas do @Sergio (que deu um ótimo exemplo de uso do `Infinity`), e do @LeoCaracciolo (que explicou como divisão por zero tende ao infinito – pode ser infinito negativo também, se o dividendo for negativo).

O que eu queria esclarecer é que essa lógica não é uma decisão direta do projeto da linguagem, e sim indireta. Todos os números em JS são representados como ponto flutuante, e a especificação de aritmética de ponto flutuante (IEEE 754) dita que a divisão por zero deve ser tratada dessa forma. O uso de exceções e outros tipos de "armadilhas" ou "ganchos" (*traps*) nesses casos é opcional, o padrão é retornar `±Infinity`.

O [FAQ da especificação](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html) justifica isso da seguinte maneira (tradução livre):

> O modelo da norma 754 encoraja a criação de programas robustos. Ele é voltado não apenas à análise numérica, mas também para usuários de planilhas, bancos de dados e até cafeteiras. As regras de propagação de NaNs e infinitudes permitem que exceções irrelevantes desapareçam (...). Quando situações excepcionais exigem tratamento, podem ser examinadas imediatamente via *traps*, ou em um momento mais conveniente via flags de status.

Answer (score 2):

Para responder a sua duvida "Minha dúvida é porque Infinity?"

Não sei exatamente se no javascript fizeram uso desse raciocínio para se chegar ao valor  `Infinity` da divisão de qualquer valor por zero.

```
1/0,1 = 10
1/0,01 = 100
1/0,001 = 1000
1/0,0001 = 10000
1/0,00001 = 100000
...................
...................
```

O divisor, quanto mais próximo de zero, maior o resultado da divisão, ou seja, um numero muito grande, gigantesco, inexplicavelmente enorme, enfim   `Infinity` 
Quanto ao uso vide resposta do amigo e Rei do Javascript Sergio